# Use of continuity in the Symmetry Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis and am a bit confused as to how the continuity of $f$ is applied to show the conditions of Morera's theorem are satisfied in the proof of the Symmetry principle. I understand that if the triangle  $T$ lies in either $\Omega^+ = \Omega \cap \mathbb{H}$ or $\Omega^- = \Omega \cap (\mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{\mathbb{H}})$ then integrating over the boundary of $T$ gives us zero, so we just need to check what happens if the triangle intersects the real line. Therefore, by shifting the triangle up by $\epsilon$ so it lies completely in $\Omega^+$, the authors claim that we can conclude by the continuity of $f$ that $\int_T f(z) dz =0$. This is the part that confuses me. If I interpret this right then we have $$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{T_{\epsilon}}f(z) dz = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_T f(z + i\epsilon) dz = \int_T f(z) dz$$ where clearly the integral on the left hand side is 0. But why does continuity allow us to take the limit inside the integral?

Comment: Define $f_{\epsilon} \colon z \mapsto f(z + i\epsilon)$. Since $f$ is continuous and $T$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous on a small neighbourhood of $T$. That implies that $f_{\epsilon} \to f$ uniformly on $T$.

Comment: The uniform convergence of $f_{\epsilon}$ on $T$ follows from the fact that $g_{\epsilon} (z) = z + i\epsilon$ converges uniformly to $g(z) = z $ on $T$ and, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, $f(g_{\epsilon}(z))$ converges uniformly to $f(g(z))$ right? This might be a silly question, but when showing the uniform convergence of $g_{\epsilon}$ does it suffice to consider $g_n(z)=z + \frac{i}{n}$ or do I need to consider $g_n(z) = z +ia_n$ where $a_n$ is an arbitrary sequence converging to 0?

Comment: We can state it thus. But I don't think introducing $g_{\epsilon}$ and $g$ makes things easier. If it helps you, that's a good reason to do it, of course. Anyway. The $f_{\epsilon}$ are just translates of $f$, and the uniform continuity of $f$ (on some neighbourhood of $T$) is at the heart of it. Regarding your second question: As written, we consider all positive real $\epsilon$, so considering one specific sequence is not enough. You can get the result by considering an *arbitrary* sequence converging to $0$, but it's in my opinion _much_ easier to give a "for every $\eta > 0$ there is a…

Comment: $\delta > 0$ such that for all $\epsilon < \delta$ etc." argument. However, you can also work with a specific sequence (e.g. $\epsilon_n = i/n$) if you reduce the claim you want to prove. You know that $\int_T f_{\epsilon}(z)\,dz = 0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. You want to show $\int_T f(z)\,dz = 0$. For that it is of course enough that $$\int_T f(z)\,dz = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_{\epsilon_n}(z)\,dz$$ holds for some sequence $(\epsilon_n)$ (this doesn't even need to converge to have the conclusion, but for the proof having $\epsilon_n \to 0$ is of course useful).

Comment: Thank you! So just to be clear, in this case I can pick a sequence $\epsilon_n >0$ such that $f_{\epsilon_n}$ converges uniformly to $f(z)$, then I can get the conclusion that I want. I think my confusion stems from the fact I have only seen uniform convergence when referring to a sequence of functions, so I wanted to find an equivalent definition to "$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} f_{\epsilon}$" which is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(z + i \epsilon_n)$ for an $\textit{arbitrary}$ sequence $\epsilon_n$ that converges to 0 right?

Comment: While one can phrase the $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}$ in terms of arbitrary sequences converging to $0$, it is better to view it differently. The "for every $\eta > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $\epsilon < \delta$ [the difference] is $< \eta$" approach is more natural.